# What machine learning benchmarks are out there?

Tags: machine-learning, benchmarking

What repositories for machine learning benchmarks do you know?

Answer (score 3):

Try the UCI Machine Learning Repository

http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/

Answer (score 2):

[MLPerf](https://mlperf.org/) appears to be the emerging industry/academia-backed ML benchmarking suite. The repo is [here](https://github.com/mlperf).

Answer (score 1):

Most machine learning systems are highly specific, and as such, a benchmark between them is not likely to be useful.

A system that works well at learning how to recognise spoken english (and thus typing up speech), would not neccessarily work well at finding the shortest path in the travelling salesperson problem.

Comment: SPEC and TCP benchmark suites cover the spectrum of workloads and thus it is reasonable to assume that a ML benchmark suite would do the same. Then potentially for very important ML applications a tailored benchmark would be of interest. Like 3DMark to test graphics performance of a computer system, we could have a Speech Recognition benchmark suite, or a Object Recognition benchmark suite.

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/libsvmtools/datasets/) there is a list (most are UCI)

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking specifically for Machine Learning applied to NLP, this is a very well curated resource:

http://nlpprogress.com/

Essentially, it's web page (github repo) to track the progress in Natural Language Processing (NLP), including the datasets and the current state-of-the-art for the most common NLP tasks.

Answer (score 0):

I've used [Weka](http://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/ml/weka/) in the past its very good and has lot of benchmarking stuff in it.

Comment: Isn't Weka a clustering tool?

Comment: I suppose clustering is a form of machine learning in some contexts, so I take back my downvote. :)

Comment: Weka sucks for clustering, actually. It is 99% classification, i.e. machine learning.

Comment: Weka is just a package/framework with implementations of several machine learning algorithms/techniques.